# What proportion of datapoints are within one standard deviation away from the mean?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called ourData with a column named Temperature(F).

I have found the count (how many) of data points within 1 std dev. using this:

```
mu <- mean(ourData$`Temperature(F)`)
s <- sd(ourData$`Temperature(F)`)
sum((ourData$`Temperature(F)` > mu - s) & (ourData$`Temperature(F)` < mu + s))
```

However, how do I find the **PROPORTION**!!

Also, how do I find the proportion of TWO(2)std dev. of mean??

i use

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
```

Comment: use `mean()` rather than `sum()` to get the proportion.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrFlick said, mean will return a proportion. To make the code more readable you could write a simple function:

```
prop <- function (x, n=1) {
  m <- mean(x); s <- n*sd(x)
  mean((x > m - s) & (x < m + s))  # eqivalent to sum(...)/length(x)
}
```

And then use it on your data:

```
prop(ourData$`Temperature(F)`)
prop(ourData$`Temperature(F)`,2) # 2 standard devations
```